# How to drop a PostgreSQL tablespace

Tags: xubuntu, postgresql

I'm just starting setting up PosgreSQL 12 on Xubuntu 20.04, so I have created some things as experiments, and I want to delete them and start over.  Hopefully without destroying everything, because even the deletion is a test.  So far all has been successful, albeit sometimes after several tries, but now I'm trying to ditch a tablespace named qubicspace, and I keep getting the error `tablespace "qubicspace" is not empty`

Logged in as my user role, I get no results from

SELECT * FROM pg_tables WHERE tablespace IS NOT NULL;

And indeed if I drop the WHERE clause and run it as postgres, I get only tables with pg_ and sql_ prefixes.

I have no idea what else to look for, so that I can clear it out.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had neglected to look for databases that lived in the tablespace.  There was one (that contained zero tables,) as seen when I queried pg_databases, and after I dropped the database it became possible to drop the tablespace.

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL tablespace is created at cluster level which means multiple database objects like table & indexes can reside into the tablespace. So before dropping the tablespace check [PostgreSQL tablespace location](https://orahow.com/check-tablespace-location-in-postgresql/) and crosscheck all objects and their referring databases.

```
**Syntax:**

DROP TABLESPACE [IF EXISTS] tablespace_name;

drop tablespace if exists tbs_test;
```

Note: If tablespace has any objects then it will throw error: tablespace is not empty. Drop all the objects before dropping the tablespace.